# Foundation.MonoTouchException in Xamarin.Forms for ios project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am doing a project in android and ios.I am getting an exception in iOS as below:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

But working fine in Android.

Any one please help me to get out of this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you updating some collection in a ListView? Please show the code you use for that.

Comment: Thanks for you response Gerald.I used ListView source as Observable collection.Now i changed it to List.It is working fine.

Comment: Issues like this should be reported to Xamarin directly, https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug